# Bootstrap Vue: How can I render custom text-field for an array of strings?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am rendering a checkbox group for an array of dates. Currently, everything is working properly--however, I would like to format the text that is rendered.

```html
<b-form-checkbox-group
    id="checkbox-group-1"
    v-model="my_dates"
    :options="options"
    name="flavour-1"
    :text-field="formattedDate(date)"
    stacked>
</b-form-checkbox-group>
```

Each checkbox has a label of `2020-09-08`.

What I would like to do is have each checkbox render something like:
`Friday, September 8th, 2020`.

Here is what an example of my .vue file looks like:

```js
// later...

data: {
    options: ['2020-09-08', '2020-09-10']
}, 
methods:{
    formattedDate(date) {
        return moment(date).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY');
    },
}
```

How can I format the text in a human friendly way? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the checkbox component uses the `value` and `text` properties if they exist, falling back to just plain strings.

See https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox#checkbox-group-options-array

What you can do is construct a computed property to reflect this

```js
computed: {
  formattedOptions: ({ options }) => options.map(value => ({
    value,
    text: moment(date).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY')
  })
}
```

Then use this in the `options` prop

```html
<b-form-checkbox-group
  id="checkbox-group-1"
  v-model="my_dates"
  :options="formattedOptions"
  name="flavour-1"
  stacked
></b-form-checkbox-group>
```